# Slider with no hidden or invisible elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, slideshow

There is container with some objects, in my case ul with li. In this container there are fixed count of object, without hidden and can't be. When I click left first object should animated go left and add from right side of the container.

In ex.

```
 1 2 3
```

press left start animate
<- 1 go left

and we have 1 2 3 1

to the right side add 1 object and it move synchronize with 1 object from left side.
animation finish and the result

```
2 3 1
```

It's almost like other sliders, but there are no hidden or invisible elements behind the container.

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <a class="left" href="#">&lt;</a>
    <div class=slider>
        <ul>
            <li class="red"></li>
            <li class="black"></li>
            <li class="yellow"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <a  class="right"  href="#">&gt;</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('a.left').on('click', function(){
    var $self = $(this);
    var $parent = $self.closest('.wrapper');
    var $ul = $parent.find('ul');
    var $first = $ul.find('li').first();
    $first.clone().appendTo($ul);
    $first.remove();    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GmanG/j8Lttyxs/5/

I have no more idea how to do this correct (animate).

Thank you.

Comment: It seems to be working. If I press the left button it does the job? What's your question exactly?

Comment: It's should be animated and speed of animation customizable.